# Moderator Nominations

Tags: discussion, moderators

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice. [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer**. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of scifi.stackexchange.com who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

It's also good if the moderators:

- Are members with participation in both meta.scifi.stackexchange.com and scifi.stackexchange.com.
- Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
- Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Comment: how long is the nominating period, when are the votes counted?

Comment: I should point out this _isn't_ an election, the mod pro tem is an appointed position, that being said your input _is_ taken into account when they are selected.

Comment: In the interests of transparency, there's been a good amount of [discussion about this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/science-fiction). (Scroll back a bit to see the mod nomination discussions.)

Comment: @Mark Rogers: Read the linked [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) blog post. It explains the whole purpose of why you are nominating moderators here.

Comment: I read it, I just wanted clarification.

Comment: Bump. Perhaps a mod could add the "featured" tag to this?

Comment: Questions do not require the [featured] tag to be displayed in the sidebar on the parent site.  Logic will pick up hot/active questions automatically.

Comment: @zypher @rebecca @robert does the SE team have any idea of timeframe here? The original post says 2 weeks, and it's been a month now.  I'm not familiar enough with the site-creation process of other SE sites to know if you're tending towards a longer time since that was written.

Answer (score 16):

**Dori**

[Dori](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/100/dori) has been a very strong participant in the [meta site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/100/dori), which I believe have been very beneficial to the community. In particular, Dori seems to have ideas which are popular in Meta, which the current mod team supports as well, including removing list questions, is something considered sci-fi, and has already been policing the site by helping to close questions that aren't worthy of the site. I believe that Dori could act as a go-between for the mods and general community, and in fact, is already helping to meet that goal.

Comment: Early in the private beta, Dori went and retagged a lot of questions, which made it easier to get an idea of what kinds of questions we had.

Answer (score 11):

**Gilles**

[Gilles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56/gilles) has 1k+ reputation, answered nearly 29 questions, and has participated strongly on [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/56/gilles) and on [many other StackExchange sites](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56/gilles?tab=accounts) (over 20k rep in total).

Gilles has made numerous constructive, well-thought-out comments across many meta questions, that indicate an ability to help guide the community to a successful site, without being overly forceful and demonstrating patience for other users.

Comment: Nevermind, Giles doesn't got the diplomacy skills.

Comment: Thanks for the nomination. If you want to judge my actions (or my diplomacy skills) on other SE sites, I'm mostly active on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) these days.

Comment: Whether I would accept the position depends on whether I still believe that SciFi.SE can *interest* me then. If the site [devolves into a trivia site](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190/what-is-scifi-ses-elevator-pitch/212#212), I'm likely to drop off.

Answer (score 7):

**Mike Scott**

[Mike Scott](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/23/mike-scott) has made good contributions both on the main site and on [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23/mike-scott). He is in the [top three users by reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users), spread over both written and film media. He also has some [sf credentials](http://www.plokta.com/).

Answer (score 1):

**Tony Meyer**

[Tony Meyer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/108/tony-meyer) has been active both on the main site, as well as in [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/108/tony-meyer) and in the chatroom. While he is new to the process of starting a StackExchange site, he has been active (at varying levels) in StackOverflow essentially since it began (with small use of ServerFault, SuperUser and other sites in the network). He seems quite capable of maintaining the post. He seems willing and able to bridge the gaps that seem to exist in our community, and has spent considerable time to help us view the state of our community. He has asked some of the best questions on the site, and has given some good answers too.

*Personal note:*

I appreciate the nomination, and I do accept it.  **I do feel that there are other users who would be better at this job than I would**, but if they aren't able to and Robert et. al. would like me to help, then I'm willing to do so.

I strongly feel that the community here is capable of taking over most of running the site from the SE moderators, and that we would strongly benefit from having moderators that were intimately familiar and involved with the discussion on *our* meta and our site.  My feeling is that - especially at first - letting the site self-moderate more would have worked more effectively than the heavy-handed approach (although I'm sure the SE moderators are doing their best).

The "SE voice" isn't as consistent as it should be (c.f. the kerfluffle over identification questions), and I hope that our pro-tem moderators work with the SE team to improve that, so that it's clearer what is up to us as a community, and what are set rules for the SE network.

It seems to me that the largest challenge we face *right now* is getting more participation on the site (more views, more good questions).  I'm not a good moderator candidate in this respect - I don't have a large audience that I can push the site to, and I live in a rather remote part of the world, so don't even interact (in real life) with many potential site users. The best I could do as a moderator here, is try and ensure that we make it clearer to users what's a good question (and what's not) for the site, so that we don't put new people off.